# get authorization url/html page

Tags: url, google-apps-script, authorization

I have a simple google script, where i check user's email (by deploying, I chose "Execute the app as: User accessing the web app"). Everything works fine in web browser. If the user didn't gave permissions to the script before, it shows the authorization page.

After authorization, I can make AJAX calls (jQuery) with dataType : 'jsonp' and I can receive the response (my JSON response). BUT without previous authorization to the script, I get an error, when I make AJAX call and the authorization HTML page is in response (I can see it in browser console), but I can't get it in jQuery to show it to the user. Is there a way to handle the authorization by my own?

Can I get the authorization URL or the authorization web page from response? The method

```
ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL).getAuthorizationUrl();
```

in Google script doesn't work, because I need permissions to run the script and afterwards I get nothing (because I gave the permission already). Thanks for any advice.

Here is the script code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread');
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  var jsonDataRes = [];
  for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      jsonDataRes.push({
        "from" : messages[i][j].getFrom(),
        "to" : messages[i][j].getTo(),
        "subject" : messages[i][j].getSubject(),
        "body" : messages[i][j].getPlainBody(),
      });
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(jsonDataRes) + ')');
}
```

And this is how I call it using jQuery and AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://script.google.com/a/macros/social-net.sk/s/*random chars*/dev?callback=?",
  dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}).always(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

This is what I get:

[image]

but the HTML is somewhere there in response (console - network tab):

[image]

Comment: You can't handle authorization on your own.

Comment: Try removing authorization after granting it. Then, check `AuthMode` and try `return`ing... Possibly requires other authorization like web publish authorization, so might not work